# How to join two tables and send data to a new Table=

Tags: google-bigquery

There are 3 tables Data, Data1, Data2 all of them have the same type of data.
How can I to join the data of Data1 and Data2 and send the data to the table Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.Data` 
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.Data1`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.Data2`
```